# Tp-Link IP configuration failure

Tags: wireless-router, repeater, ipconfig

I tried to setup my WiFi router (Tp-Link TL-WR841N) as a repeater via following the way described here:[**How to configure WDS function on TP-Link Wireless Routers(green UI)**](https://www.tp-link.com/ae/faq-227.html). It works temporarily however after some time it fails to connect to the internet. Although I can connect to the router via the Laptop's WiFi; I cannot access the admin page neither I can access using ethernet cable as no IP address would land me to the admin page. 
Also, I am not able to connect my phone to the router as it says IP configuration failure.

Comment: Have you reset your router and tried again?

Comment: Tried doing that once but problem occurred again. Need a permanent fix.

Comment: What model is your main WiFi router / access point? I have a slight suspicion that it doesn't accept WDS connections from your repeater, and it only works when you're connecting to the main AP...

Comment: same model... I have the root access to it so I can make any changes necessary